# How to refactor UIPageViewcontroller to work with a single Viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I have followed this [awesome tutorial](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/12/23/swift-uipageviewcontroller-tutorial/) by [Jeff Burt](https://twitter.com/jeffburtjr).

However my needs require it to be refactored, as my changing content will be unique ID that is hidden and a UIButton's background image.

I tried to follow other tutorials that work like this, but they are either not converting well to Swift 3 and/or I lack the experience to fully comprehend and merge them together.

The above tutorial uses already existing Storyboard ViewControlles and instantiates them with their Storyboard ID. Instead I'd like to have 1 VC then fill its content programatically as I swipe between pages rather then having separate VC's for the separate pages.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear, could you explain better what you want to do?

Comment: @IanBell I have updated my question. Sorry must have deleted it somehow before submitting it :).. 

I hope this clarifies

Comment: sorry to tell you this butI still dont understand your question even after the update

Comment: Blimey...

Have you had a look at the tutorial? 
It has a PageViewController and 3 ViewControllers that serve as pages and they are being instantiated by thier Storyboard ID.

For pages, I would like to have only 1 viewcontroller and be able to pass data to it. (Background, UIButton bg etc)

@zombie

Comment: take a look at this https://github.com/hyperoslo/Pages

Comment: @BenS UIPageViewController has methods to add viewcontrollers: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipageviewcontroller/1614087-setviewcontrollers

Comment: http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/easy-steps-to-implement-uipageviewcontroller-in-swift

Comment: thanks, will have a look later on.

Comment: Thanks for the links guys, the appguruz link helped to achieve what I wanted but the github link will be in my toolkit as well